# what is the use of UIWebview+AFNetworking class?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, afnetworking

I have observed in AFNetworking class 2.5.4 that UIKit+AFNetworking folder has been included.What is the use of various classes used in that folder and How can post request in a webview using UIWebview+AFNetworking class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This category adds methods to the UIKit framework’s UIWebView class.

The methods in this category provide increased control over the request cycle, including progress monitoring and success / failure handling.